# .htaccess Removing the folder name in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to remove these unnecessary names from my link

```
domain.com/user/profile/12/jhgH
domain.com/sec/setting/11/yjutg
domain.com/policy/privcy/10/help
```

in this way

```
domain.com/12/jhgH
domain.com/11/yjutg
domain.com/10/help
```

I have used this code and it has been successful

```
RewriteRule ^use/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /user/profile/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /sec/setting/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /policy/privcy/$1/$2 [L]
```

But only the first and second work, the third does not

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/policy/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /policy/privcy/$1/$2 [L]
```

If I bring the third code, the first one works, but the third code doesn't work.
So I tried to change the law to this one
But it didn't work either.
Is there any way I can fix this problem.

Comment: The pattern in your first rule (ie. `^use/([0-9]+)/(.*)$`) does not match any of your example URLs?! The second and third rules both have the _same_ pattern, ie. `^([0-9]+)/(.*)$` - so the first rule will always "win" and the third rule will never be successful. Your 3 example URLs all look to have _same_ pattern, except possibly the third URL has the word "help"? If you need to rewrite in 3 different ways then you need to have 3 different source URL patterns.

Comment: Although how are these URLs ultimately being routed? What you are trying to do here would not normally work unless you have a very specific front-controller, or you are perhaps rewriting to static files?!

Comment: It's really important to do it that way. If I edit it, most of my code will break and I have to edit it again

Comment: Based on _what_ do you expect your system you recognize, which of those three shorter URLs is supposed to point to a user profile, a setting, or a policy? That could only make sense, if you made that dependent on something like the numbers that are left in the URL - 12 would mean a user profile, 11 would mean a setting, and 10 a policy ... is that the case? (Your currently shown attempts to write the patterns, do _not_ suggest it was.)

Comment: 10 -11-12 = id user

Comment: Don't you see that your proposed URL structure is ambiguous? eg. Given a request for `/13/xyab`, how would you expect that to be rewritten? What is the intended target URL?  Is it `/user/profile/13/xyab`, `/sec/setting/13/xyab` or `/policy/privcy/13/xyab` (or something else?!)